# Read Delimited File That Wraps Lines

Tags: python, csv, numpy

I apologize if there is an obvious answer to this already.

I have a very large file that poses a few challenges for parsing.  I am delivered these files from outside my organization, so there is no chance I can change their format.

Firstly, the file is space delimited but the fields that represent a "column" of data can span multiple rows.  For example, if you had a row that was supposed to be 25 columns of data, it may be written in the file as:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14
   15 16 17 18 19 20 21 
  22 23 24 25
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13
   14 15 16 17 18
  19 20 21 22 23 24 25
```

As you can see, I can't rely on each set of data being on the same line, but I can rely on there being the same number of columns per set.

To make matters worse, the file follows a definition:data type format where the first 3 or so lines will be describing the data (including a field that tells me how many rows there are) and the next N rows are data.  Then it will go back to the 3 lines format again to describe the next set of data.  That means I can't just set up a reader for the N columns format and let it run to EOF.

I'm afraid the built in python file reading functionality could get really ugly real fast, but I can't find anything in csv or numpy that works.

Any suggestions?

EDIT: Just as an example of a different solution:

We have an old tool in MATLAB that parses this file using textscan on an open file handle.  We know the number of columns so we do something like:

```
data = textscan(fid, repmat('%f ',1,n_cols), n_rows, 'delimiter', {' ', '\r', '\n'}, 'multipledelimsasone', true);
```

This would read the data no matter how it wrapped while leaving a file handle open to process the next section later.  This is done because the files are so large they can lead to excess RAM usage.

Comment: Doing so would require a government entity to redeliver a massive set of files to hundreds of organizations while potentially breaking the parsers.

Comment: Ask the provider for the correct parser???

Comment: `np.genfromtxt` accepts input that will feed it lines.  A list of lines is a simple example.  Or a filter function that reads your file, cleans it up block by block, and pssses a reconstructed line back.

Comment: Can you detect the three line header somehow or is it also just numbers?

Comment: The only way to detect the header is by knowing that you just ended the last data block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a sketch how you can proceed:
(EDIT: with some modifications)

```
file = open("testfile.txt", "r") 

# store data for the different sections here
datasections = list()

while True:
    current_row = []

    # read three lines

    l1 = file.readline()
    if line == '': # or other end condition
        break
    l2 =  file.readline()
    l3 =  file.readline()

    # extract the following information from l1, l2, l3
    nrows = # extract the number rows in the next section
    ncols = # extract the number of columns in the next section


    # loop while len(current_row) < nrows * ncols:

        # read next line, isolate the items using str.split()
        # append items to current_row


    # break current_row into the lines after each ncols-th item
    # store data in datasections in a new array
```

Comment: This would work if the nrows corresponded to the number of actual rows in the file.  Due to the line wrapping, the nrows will be a much smaller number than the actual number for rows in the file.  Additionally, these files are huge (5+ GB) so reading all at once is taxing.  I'm starting to think this might get ugly.

Comment: Ok, first you want to read the file line by line. Then instead of reading *nrows* you would read one line and check how many items of the current section you have. If its more then *nrows x ncols* you would close the section.  Maybe you should provide a full (but stripped down) example of a small valid input.

Comment: I think some kind of datum counter might have to be the solution, I'm just worried about performance losses with that.